# Can't Bulk Install Modules in DNN 9.10.2

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dnn9

With newer versions of DNN, they excluded the Bulk Install files used to bulk install modules.

We used to copy the following files in the install folder on newer versions to make it work.
[image]

When I navigate the following URL, I get an Exception: dnndev.me/install/install.aspx?mode=installresources

Exception:
[image]

It looks like a missing definition in a DLL.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade.Upgrade.CheckUpgrade() is no longer exist on latest version of DNN.

Check the [history](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/commit/52925622e6b9eb168e9a1f328f719712168d2244#diff-99e535df3994cc154899ea067ff664f4494a1f3b0d8a0ec530acc69edb4febeaL588) related to it

Don't just paste your old code, there's a couple update at DNN Install.aspx.cs file.
You'll need to make adjustment to it.